# Spring @Autowired not working - BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, autowired

When I try to deploy file on server error occurs. I'm confused, because this code  was working.

**Exception**

```
    Failed to enable lec2ear-1.0.ear.

Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "lecture_7")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./mart-parent" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./mart-parent: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storageController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ru.menkin.ea.lec4.model.services.ICategoryService ru.menkin.ea.lec5.controllers.StorageController._categoryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ru.menkin.ea.lec4.model.repositories.CategoryRepository ru.menkin.ea.lec4.model.services.CategoryService.categoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/recipeDs
Error Code: 0
```

**ICategoryService**

```
public interface ICategoryService
{
    public Category create(Category category);
    public Category delete(int id) throws Exception;
    public List<Category> findAll();
    public Category update(Category category) throws Exception;
    public Category findById(int id);
}
```

**his implementation**

```
public class CategoryService implements ICategoryService
{
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
...
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
public class StorageController extends BaseController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("categoryService")
    private ICategoryService _categoryService;
...
```

**database.xml**

```
<djpa:repositories base-package="ru.menkin.ea.lec4.model" />

<bean id="categoryService" class="ru.menkin.ea.lec4.model.services.CategoryService" />
```

**beans.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.menkin.ea" />
```

Where my mistake?

Comment: Post the full stacktrae.

Comment: Is `CategoryService` annotated with `@Service`?

Comment: Now No, but I trying to add this annotation.

Comment: Have you read the stack trace? The actual cause? Your db setup is wrong.

Comment: from your stacktrace, the problem lies on `CategoryRepository` which has a property `mappingContext` trying to map it to `jpaMappingContext`. Can you check you database connection settings?

Comment: Thank you, I really forgot about the connection to the database. Oh, those New Year holidays!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here last cause in your exception message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException
```

Spring could not invoke the init method of your `jpaMappingContext` because a persistence exception occured - Something went wrong in the database.

So, Spring autowiring is actually working, but it cannot autowire your dependency because of a database problem that occurs when initializing one of the spring beans.

So something in the database or database settings changed since this code last worked. Analyze the full stack trace to find out the root cause of this issue - Which is a database problem.

Comment: Thank you. Problem was with database connection. Autowired is working. ))

Comment: David - Could u please guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685804/how-to-make-database-configuration-configurable-of-persistance-xml-file-through?

Comment: The problem was my server was not started. lol  Thanks a lot