# getting ***BeanCreationException*** pls suggest a solution to solve this

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My requirement is to insert the supplier along with catalogue and I only want to unidirectional mapping. Is there is anyway to resolve it with unidirectional only because I want to fetch catalogues from supplier(supplierId) and I am new to stackoverflow if there is any editing mistake please comment down, I will fix it.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'supplierRepository' defined in com.inventory.repository.SupplierRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.inventory.entities.Supplier, at table: catalog, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(supplier)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.inventory.SpringBootInventoryAssignmentApplication.main(SpringBootInventoryAssignmentApplication.java:9) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.inventory.entities.Supplier, at table: catalog, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(supplier)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.inventory.entities.Supplier, at table: catalog, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(supplier)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.inventory.entities.Supplier, at table: catalog, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(supplier)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:499) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:466) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:227) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Entities
*Catalog.java*

```
package com.inventory.entities;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

@Entity
@Table(name = "catalog")
public class Catalog {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int skuCode;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String skuName;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String skuDesc;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String bName;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String bDesc;
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    private Supplier supplier;// FK

    public Catalog() {
    }

    public Catalog(String skuName, String skuDesc, String bName, String bDesc, Supplier supplier) {
        this.skuName = skuName;
        this.skuDesc = skuDesc;
        this.bName = bName;
        this.bDesc = bDesc;
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public int getSkuCode() {
        return skuCode;
    }

    public String getSkuName() {
        return skuName;
    }

    public void setSkuName(String skuName) {
        this.skuName = skuName;
    }

    public String getSkuDesc() {
        return skuDesc;
    }

    public void setSkuDesc(String skuDesc) {
        this.skuDesc = skuDesc;
    }

    public String getbName() {
        return bName;
    }

    public void setbName(String bName) {
        this.bName = bName;
    }

    public String getbDesc() {
        return bDesc;
    }

    public void setbDesc(String bDesc) {
        this.bDesc = bDesc;
    }

    public Supplier getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(Supplier supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Catalog [skuCode=" + skuCode + ", skuName=" + skuName + ", skuDesc=" + skuDesc + ", bName=" + bName
                + ", bDesc=" + bDesc + ", supplier=" + supplier + "]";
    }

}
```

*Supplier.java*

```
package com.inventory.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;

@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier")
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int supplierId;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String supplierName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Catalog> catalogList;

    public Supplier() {
        this.catalogList = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
    }

    public Supplier(String supplierName) {
        this.supplierName = supplierName;
        this.catalogList = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
    }

    public int getSupplierId() {
        return supplierId;
    }

    public String getSupplierName() {
        return supplierName;
    }

    public void setSupplierName(String supplierName) {
        this.supplierName = supplierName;
    }

    public List<Catalog> getCatalogList() {
        return catalogList;
    }

    public void setCatalogList(List<Catalog> catalogList) {
        this.catalogList = catalogList;
    }

}
```

***Service Classes***
*CatalogService*

```
package com.inventory.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.inventory.entities.Catalog;
import com.inventory.repository.CatalogRepository;
import com.inventory.service.CatalogService;

@Service
public class CatalogServiceImpl implements CatalogService {
    
    @Autowired
    private CatalogRepository catalogRepository;
    
    @Override
    public Catalog getCatalogById(int id) {
        return catalogRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Catalog saveCatalog(Catalog catalog) {
        return catalogRepository.save(catalog);
    }
    
}
```

*SupplierServiceImpl*

```
package com.inventory.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.inventory.entities.Supplier;
import com.inventory.repository.SupplierRepository;
import com.inventory.service.SupplierService;

@Service
public class SupplierServiceImpl implements SupplierService {
    
    @Autowired
    private SupplierRepository supplierRepository;

    @Override
    public Supplier getSupplierById(int id) {
        return supplierRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Supplier insertSupplier(Supplier supplier) {
        return supplierRepository.save(supplier);
    }
    
    

}
```

I also want to know how to write search query for for item name in spring boot. Suppose, supplier A have Lays potato chips, banana chips, masala chips, coffee.  I want to
search catalog items based on its supplierID and when I search for "chips" then it shows all types of chips supplier A have  in catalog then how can I write such queries in CrudRepository/JpaRepository so that I can use it in service layer.

Comment: see it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738498/spring-autowired-not-working-beancreationexception and it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394856/spring-data-jpa-jpamappingcontext-error-illegalstateexception-expected-to-be/62836255

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate with @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Supplier supplier;
```

---

Update (15/02/21)

As you added that you want an unidirectional relationship, this is the way, in the catalog class:

```
@Column
private int supplierId;
```

You can remove the supplier field or mark it as @Transient.

You must save the supplier, get its id (as it is generated by the database), and set it in your catalog.

Comment: Yeah I did it but I need unidirectional sorry I forgot to add that in question